# How to fade/blend between 2 divs in a less 'clunky' way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

NB

My Header:

```
<header>
    <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px;">
       <div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;margin-top:55px;background-color:#2BC3A7; height:3px; width:200px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="clear:both;float:left;"></div>
        <div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;margin-top:5px;font-family:DIN; font-size:12pt;color:#2BC3A7;">Services/Products</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I have 2 divs:

```
<div id="#content1">
    <div id="divWelcome" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <div id="headerimg" style="position: relative;">
            <div style="position: absolute; bottom:255px; left: 20px; width: 550px; font-family:DIN; font-size:23pt; font-weight:600; color: white; letter-spacing:0.01em;">
                We offer Cloud solutions for small businesses to help them manage their workflow requirements
            </div>

            <hr style="height:6px;position: absolute; bottom:210px; left: 20px; width: 490px;"/>


            <div style="position: absolute; bottom:175px; left: 20px; width: 550px; font-family:DIN; font-size:14pt; font-weight:500; color: white; letter-spacing:0.01em;">
               Our core sectors of expertise are professional services, data management and outsourcing.
            </div>

        </div>


        <div id="divAboutContents" style="margin-top:50px; background-color:red;position: relative;display: none;">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

So when the page loads the 1st div shows. The effect I want is when the user presses a button the `divFirst` gently fades away and the `divSecond` gently fades in. I have used this bit of jQuery but the affect does not look very pleasing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divAbout").click(function () {
            $("#headerimg").fadeOut();
            $("#divAboutContents").fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
```

What else can I try/read up on? Thanks

NB
This is part of my CSS

```
#content1 {
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Also I was fading the other one out. just forgot to put it in the question. The affect I get is 'clunky'

Comment: What does "not pleasing" mean? Could you post a jsfiddle of your current solution?

Comment: @GMchris you are quite right. I shall attempt to do so after looking at the answer submitted. tahnks

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/9b4juatm/ , you can specify how slow -*or fast*- the fadeOut/in happens like `.fadeOut(2000)` where 2000 means 2000 milli-second

Answer (score 4):

'Pleasing' is a very subjective term, however to improve it you could place both `div` elements within a parent container positioned absolutely so they overlap. You can then `fadeToggle()` between the two as needed. Something like this:

```js
$('#container').click(function() {
  $(this).find('div').fadeToggle();
})
```

```css
#container > div {
  position: absolute;
}
#divSecond {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="divFirst">some content with images</div>
  <div id="divSecond">different content with images</div>
</div>
```

Click the text to see the fade transition in action.

Comment: Ok, if you edit the HTML in to the question I'll have a look for you.

Comment: The same solution does work for the HTML you've shown. The issue was that you have several inline `position: relative` rules set which break the layout. Try this one: https://jsfiddle.net/g8zcb9Ld/1/. Note that I had to remove the `bottom` and `left` properties for the HTML to be visible in the fiddle.

Comment: my comment seems to have disappeared. What I had put was this:  By removing the bottom and left properties my header line and secondary text disappear. I had used these to over-lay onto my image.  Still when running as you indicated it did not work. Nothing happened, The only difference I can see is that I am using an image as the back ground in my 1st div